# How to add date_query to meta_query array

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, get-posts, date-query

I am building a meta query array and all fields for the user are optional so some might not have any data. But there is also an option which requires a date query. I am still checking to see if this is working but not sure as of yet. Is this correct and if not, what would be the right way to do it? Not sure if there needs to be an OR condition in here somewhere.

```
$meta_query = [];
$date_query = [];

if ( $gender != '' ) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'gender',
        'value' => $gender,
        'compare' => '='
    ];
}

if ( $age != '' ) {
     $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'age',
        'value' => $age,
        'compare' => '='
    ];
}

if ( $userDate != 0 ) {
    $date_query[] = [
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month
    ];
}

$args = [
    'post_type' => 'person',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'date_query' => $date_query

];

$data = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Post meta queries are expensive but you've used `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`, aside from caching the result, you should set the `suppress_filters` option to `false` otherwise this query will be totally uncached even with caching plugins. You should also change `posts_per_page` to a high number you never expect to reach but know your server can handle, not `-1`. Also `gender` could easily be part of a `tax_query` which would provide another performance boost, same with `age`, use taxonomies not post meta for data you need to group/search/filter by

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks for your info. Ah right, `supress_filters` is only default of false for `wp_query` and not `get_posts`. I don't think I am following with your `tax_query` suggestion as the fields I am referring to are custom meta fields and not taxonomy fields?

Comment: that's right, you would need to change how that data is stored to use custom taxonomies instead of post meta. Post meta is optimised for when you know which post ID the meta belongs to, but doing the reverse gets very expensive. How expensive depends on the size of your post meta table, so it will seem lightning fast on a site with a handful of posts, but it may bring down databases on very large sites. Taxonomies were built for the opposite problem, finding post IDs when you already know the name/value